# Remove hyphen from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the hyphen from a variable if it is a negative number, but when using the replace function I get 'undefined is not a function'.

```
var extraDivs = checkNumDivs.length - 20;

if (extraDivs <= -1) {
    extraDivsNoDash = extraDivs.replace("-", "");
    $('.title a').html('Add ' + extraDivsNoDash);
} else {
    $('.title a').html('Remove ' + extraDivs);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use `.replace` on a string.
Try this:

```
extraDivsNoDash = (extraDivs + '').replace("-", "");
//                             ^ this converts the number to a string.
```

Or, to actually convert the integer to a positive number using [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
extraDivsNoDash = Math.abs(extraDivs);
```

Comment: @C-linkNepal: What? I have no clue what you're trying to say.

Comment: You are saying replace works on a string but again saying to convert in positive number that I couldn't understand...

Comment: @C-linkNepal: Try to understand, line for line, exactly what the OP is trying to do. Then see what my changes to his code actually _do_.

Comment: +1. If it is a number, treat it as a number. So using the absolute function does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct with "**hyphen**" you mean "**minus**" symbol here, i.e you want to convert a signed number as unsigned one.

Here is a straight forward solution to your problem :-

Just use:

```
 Math.abs(extraDivs);
```

This will take care of your problem and will give you the positive number as result.

Here is the code you need to write:

```
 if (extraDivs <= -1) {    
          $('.title a').html('Add ' + Math.abs(extraDivs));
    }
else{
         //your code
}
```

Hope this would help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .abs method in Math

```
var extraDivs = Math.abs(checkNumDivs.length - 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this? I think it's the most simple, lightweight and straightforward option:

```
var extraDivs = checkNumDivs.length - 20;

var text;
if (extraDivs < 0) {
    text = 'Add ' + -extraDivs;
} else {
    text = 'Remove ' + extraDivs;
}

$('.title a').html(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

And if Math.abs is to mainstream for your liking (I don't recommend this, though.)

```
var extraDivs = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(extraDivs), 2);
```

editted @Anton

Comment: Don't... Why would you even suggest this.

Comment: superfluous bracket `)` at the end. And this doesn't work it returns `NaN`? or am i doing it wrong.